# Tag changes not getting saved while editing a question

Tags: support, bug, android-app

I'm trying to edit the below question, which is basically a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) question but has been mistakenly tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23):

[image]

But after doing the necessary changes as shown below:

[image]

Clicking on `<-` arrow brings back the same preview with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag. Neither could I find a button nor something viable to update the `tag`. There is no clear indication that the `tag` has been changed. Preview is also showing the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag and **not** [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

I didn't submit the changes because of this. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious here?

I'm using Stack Overflow v1.0.4 Android app