# Imgur returning 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: bug, status-completed, imgur

Just saw that Imgur complains about images presumably containing errors.

They were up for 2 years and most certainly do not contain errors.

Has anybody seen this lately?

[Here is the post...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204274/panel-drawing-zoom-in-c/32204516#32204516)

And here is one of them:

[image: Unavailable image]

Comment: Two other examples of broken images uploaded today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683081/user-input-errors-illegal-start-of-expression-and-type and https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46683313/1

Comment: This is systemwide; none of the i.stack.imgur images are available for me.

Comment: Another image suffered same fate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQQ9l.png. Some code posted as images in new questions also not showing up.

Comment: Yep, I repaired a [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46651803/472495), I've fixed it using the standard imgur.com domain for now.

Comment: We are getting in touch with imgur - they have been doing some maintenance work and the service has been flaky in the last few days.

Comment: @halfer The correct "repair" there would have been to transcribe those images into text. Failing that...vote to close.

Comment: The profile image of OP (also i.stack.imgur.com) is showing, yet if I expand the usercard it is gone. Also my own profile image in the top-bar is gone. It's not only limited to (recently uploaded) images in posts.

Comment: Can confirm the issue in several other posts, but thought it was only me...

Comment: Can confirm for [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682151/why-python-cv2-resize-function-on-rgb-image-gives-different-results-than-matlab). This was happening yesterday also, I could not upload an image

Comment: This does not seem to happen with new posts (or always), as my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357688/tag-changes-not-getting-saved-while-editing-a-question) seems unaffected

Comment: @o_O Note that OPsaid that those images were around for quite some times, so maybe they changed something and didn't handled properly old images.

Comment: @o_O: But __I can't see your images, either__! Note __the upload works__ but the __images are not displayed__! - Well I tried to re-add those old images, saved as with a new name and the issue persisted, so it is not just about old images! And as can be seen abvoe it also happend for this new post.

Comment: Hmm.. Dunno what's happening. I can see the images in my question but not on few others

Comment: Ok, seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Please post an answer if you're certain this has been fixed. Preferably wait for a developer to actually confirm it's been fixed. Don't edit your question with a solution or words like "[fixed]".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have contacted imgur about this - sorry it took a while - I noticed it at 5am US Eastern Time when I woke up and immediately notified imgur however I believe the issue had started well before then.

Imgur have reported that they have solved the issue at their end, but please let us know if this continues to happen.

[image]

(as proof of image upload image working)