# Screen rotation discards comment drafts and creates a prompt for question drafts

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, stack-overflow-app, draft

I've been using the SO App for Android regularly since installing it a couple weeks ago, but I've noticed a few glitchy things. I'll stick with the one that's frustrated me the most:

Turning my device 90° (thus rotating the screen from portrait to landscape) has "undesirable effects" in certain areas of the app.

If I am midway through entering a Comment:

[image: A]

...and then I turn my phone sideways (so it's easier to type), my partially finished comment disappears, and I'm back on the Question page, as if I clicked a Cancel button:

[image: B]

...**however**, if I am partway through "Asking a Question":

[image: C]

And then I do *nothing more* than rotate the phone like before, it now responds as if I  Save or Exit button, presenting a dialog with choice of starting my question over, or resuming my draft:

[image: D]

Ironically, I can rotate *that* screen back to portrait and the nice responsive dialog re-positions itself:

[image: E]

If I leave and then later go back to the "Ask" screen I am again presented with a choice of New or Resume

[image: F]

And then the "Answer" section behaves differently *yet again*.  Typing an answer...

[image: G]

I rotate the screen and it's... absolutely fine!  No warnings, no lost data, I can just keep on typing:

[image: H]

What's up with that?

> Android 4.4.2 (rooted) on
>
> an (otherwise problem-free) Samsung Galaxy S3
>
> SO App version 1.0.4 / June 30, 2017

---

### Update:

I switched to the [SE App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin). Rotation and other bugs from the SO App are not an issue, plus it's a cleaner interface overall, and seems to use less background data even though it's delivering notifications for 12 SE sites as well as SO.

I originally opted for the SO App since I assumed its' existence implied that it had features specific to SO, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I wonder what the original reasoning was for creating a separate app.

Comment: I don't use the SO mobile app but your question here sounds on-topic to me:)

Comment: @Martin James, I kind of sensed that - I tried searching around for the correct place to post this and couldn't find any solid info.  One post suggested posting here.  Any suggestions?  Am I at least correct that the [tag:android-app] tag is for the topic of the Mobile SO App?

Comment: Incidentally I also emailed androidapp@stackoverflow.com a link to this page, perhaps whoever mans that email will point me in a better direction, if this isn't the correct place for this

Comment: Actually I believe this is correct place for such discussion, as there are a few bugs I have noticed in the iOS app too. Which I would like to point out, I am just waiting for the discussion to breakout here.

Comment: Yeah, [here's the instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) for bug reporting... they point here.  Perhaps someone monitors this tag for reports...

Comment: [One of the annoying problem that I faced with SO Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357688/tag-changes-not-getting-saved-while-editing-a-question)

Comment: Oh good, more bugs that I haven't even noticed yet!  Thanks for sharing --  Anyone else have SO-App bugs to report, or is it only the three of us? (lol)  I do like the app and use it daily, and I know it's new... I just find it a little ironic that the "most buggy app" I have is for the site where I go when I need help with my bugs.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... **Is** is in beta?  Did I miss a disclaimer somewhere?  Still no response to this properly tagged post (as instructed)...  oh well, in meantime I guess I'll just avoid the buggy features,

Comment: Worth noting that, as far as I know, this app is no longer being maintained. Stack Exchange disbanded the mobile app development team earlier this year, and they aren't going to be introducing any new features or fixing anything but critical bugs. Why not just use the mobile version of the website? It is far more functional, and far less buggy. I haven't found anything that the app can do that the mobile website can't do. The reverse is obviously far from true.

Comment: @Cody Gray -- are we talking about the same version?  I was under the impression (without confirming right this second) that there have been a total of 1 SE app and 2 SO apps, this being a fairly recent release?

Comment: Oh… I might have been confusing it with the Stack Exchange app. Not sure if the Stack Overflow app is still being maintained. It was never clear to me why there were two different apps that offered essentially the same features. Nor why they would choose to maintain the one limited to Stack Overflow, instead of the one targeting a larger audience.

Comment: Yeah good points.  [This link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/8112776) leads me to believe the SO app is <6months old. I haven't tried the SE app, I just assumed there was a good reason (based on functionality specific to programmers who use SO) that they have gone to the trouble of creating a separate app.

Comment: The SE app used to have problems like this, but hasn't for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the SO app is not handling Activity recreation correctly on rotation.  Really for an app this complex it should probably turn it off and handle rotation itself, or lock itself into portrait mode if it isn't ready to do that.  Android rotation handling is pretty damn horrible in general, they made some design decisions that worked for the very simple apps they thought would exist around 1.0 but have not scaled well to modern apps.

Comment: Yeah I usually keep Rotation turned off but this is one of the few cases I want it on, so it is easier to read & respond to posts.  Looks like there is no solution (or response to bug reports) so, for lack of response I'll accept this answer so you get the points. Thanks.

Comment: @ashleedawg there aren’t any points on meta. If the issue isn’t solved you should leave the question open.

Comment: Accepting the answer doesn't close the question either @MartinSmith

Comment: "Android rotation handling is pretty damn horrible in general" Yeh I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I like it because it means that if an app supports rotation (common) it also supports it when the Facebook app uses all the memory and Android suspends all the other apps in self defense.

Comment: @ZanLynx Except it doesn't.  Its one line to turn that off, and I don't know a single major app that doesn't turn off recreation on rotation.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I don't know of any big apps that lose your content on being destroyed, either.

Comment: @Martin No point on meta, I forgot... unaccepted.

Comment: @Braiam a bug report with an accepted answer gives the impression that the issue was closed satisfactorily in some way.